# ICallbackEventHandler, HttpHandler, XMLHttpRequestObjext - which is the better method

Tags: .net, javascript, ajax

Out of the the three (ICallbackEventHandler, HttpHandler, or XMLHttpRequest Object) Which is the better method to use?  Are they essentially the same?  Are ICallbackEventHandler and HttpHandler just variations of using the XMLHttpRequestObject?

Answer (score 0):

HttpHandler is a server-side type. XMLHttpRequest is client-side. I don't know what the other is.